# OnTrac tracking number format and checksums

Tags: checksum

I'm working on a shipping [tracking number](https://github.com/jkeen/tracking_number) library and would like to add support for [OnTrac](http://www.ontrac.com/).

Based on some sample numbers (e.g. `C10999911320231`, `C10999606576777`, `C11001105367744`), the format seems to be a `C` followed by 14 digits, where the first digit is always a `1`.  Are there other formats?

There also appears to be a checksum, as Google only recognizes certain variations (e.g. `C10999911320231` works, but `C10999911320232` does not).  I tried various algorithms but couldn't work it out.  How is the checksum calculated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tracking number is a `C` followed by 14 digits, where the last digit is the check-digit.  The check-digit calculation is identical to [UPS](http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/207899.html), including converting the `C` to a `4`.  Thanks to Danielle at OnTrac for providing this information.

Answer (score 0):

Now it's also possible that an OnTrac tracking number starts with `D`. To calculate the check digit, `D` needs to be replaced with a `5` before calculating the check digit.

See [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21224/Calculating-the-UPS-Tracking-Number-Check-Digit) and [here](https://github.com/jkeen/tracking_number_data/) for sample code to calculate the check digit.